# Hover command not releasing

Tags: jquery, hover

What I'm trying to accomplish is when I hover over a button, the specified classes fade out, then once I'm no longer hovering, for the classes to go back to 100% opacity.

From what I understand, a .hover is active only when the mouse is over the selected object. When my mouse leaves however, the opacity of the selected object stays at what is defined for the .hover state. How do I get the selected classes to go back to 100% opacity when the mouse is no longer hovering?

```
$(".si").hover(function () {
  $(".maq, .cm, .ac, .qm, .nm, .lon, .pp, .cl, .av, .amb, .hub").fadeTo(500, 0.4);
```

});

Comment: *" a .hover is active only when the mouse is over the selected object."* That is correct, if you are using css and `:hover`.

Comment: Possible css solution? http://jsfiddle.net/a38Mu/3/ of course depends on your layout. Might have to add some additional tweaks to get it to work in oldIE

Comment: Thanks @Kevin B
I really like that, that would also save me from having to redo that line for every single button. Way less code. I'll have to play around with that.

Comment: Note, you can avoid that issue in js too by using methods such as .siblings etc. Give all of those menu items a common class and just select that one class, then on hover, select the siblings and fade them out. `$(".item").hover(function(){$(this).siblings().fadeTo(500, 0.4);},etc...);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)** takes two handler which is fired when your mouse enter and leave the element.

Currently you're only handle the first case which is `mouseenter`, so you can reset to the original state using second handler:

```
$(".si").hover(function () {
    $(".maq, .cm, .ac, .qm, .nm, .lon, .pp, .cl, .av, .amb, .hub").fadeTo(500, 0.4);
}, function() {
    $(".maq, .cm, .ac, .qm, .nm, .lon, .pp, .cl, .av, .amb, .hub").fadeTo(500, 1);
});
```

Comment: Thank You @felix! That worked like a charm, that makes so much more sense. Thanks for helping out a noobie with his first line of jQuery!